# Moving projects in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6.1

Currently, my Xcode Projects are in ~/Desktop/Xcode Projects/
I'd like to move all projects to ~/Desktop/Xcode Projects/Training/
One of these directories contains Classes I've defined.

Can I move Xcode 6 projects from Finder/Terminal or from within Xcode?

I'm using defaults under Xcode 6.1 (Git repository, and "Relative to Group" files.

My StackOverflow searches show steps for Xcode 4.  Is this cleaner in Xcode 6??

Any solution or pointer to docs would be appreciated!

Comment: Aside from the git files, I've moved Xcode project as simple as dragging the project folder to its new location. Been doing this over different machines. I might loose my 'snapshots' and related files not in the folder, but simply moving a project does not break its linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the projects from one location to other should not cause any issue. 
Regarding the group files that you have linked in the project file you can just that file in the Mac and re-link the same. Mostly it should be just changing the versions number of Xcode.

Nor sure about your Git config though.

Comment: I didn't think it would be as easy as drag and drop.  I didn't want to experiment, and break any Xcode internals. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I want to warn about a few possible complications, though.

First, if you've set a Custom Working Directory (e.g. via the Scheme) that pointed to a folder that you're dragging, it won't automatically update to the new location.

Second, if you've linked to custom libraries or frameworks and the path was saved relative to your project folder (which is the default behavior in XCode) then the path to these may be broken.

Oh, and the local git stuff should be fine, since git uses relative paths.